# Keep sticky nav sticky when divs are deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Morning,

I have a onepage website that is using a sticky navigation. I would like to delete a couple of divs but when I do, the sticky navigation no longer sticks when you scroll down.  I can add spacers but that will add extra/empty space. How can I delete the menu card div and faq div and still make the navigation stick to the top and not jump the way it does now?

Link: mktminc.com/ecraftinc/new/onepage.html

Any help would be appreciateed.

Comment: What about giving us a minimal example of your issue, hosted somewhere else like JSfiddle?

Comment: I just inspected your site, and deleted a couple of DIVS in the main body and sticky navigation works just fine. Can you elaborate on which DIVS are you trying to delete

Comment: Tasos, the divs I am referring to would be the section id "Menu Card" and the class "overlay-iverlay scale"

Comment: Well i just deleted the two you mentioned above and the sticky menu works. If you want to try, using Google chrome right click anywhere on your site and inspect element, find the DIVS and rightclick and select (Delete Node) to delete each  DIV

Comment: @Tasos, I tried that and it works for me in Firefox Firebug as well but when I delete the actual divs in the html file it doesn't work. I'm thinking I have to change/add to a "top" somewhere in one of the javascript files.

Comment: @Tasos, this is what I was talking about. Not sure how to keep the nav from scrolling up the page.